# Angular13, fix Id number error on table - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am preparing a project like below with Angular 13. There does not appear to be any problem, but after registering I get an error as follows

When I remove the "RowExpansion" html range I get no errors. But when the rowexpansion is added, I am constantly getting an error like the one below. I can't get past this error, can you help?

I get an error after making a new record

**Html**

```
  <p-toast></p-toast>

  <div style="height: calc(100vh - 149px)" id="id">
    <p-table #dt [value]="categoryList"
            styleClass="p-datatable-company"
            dataKey="id"
            editMode="row"
            [tableStyle]="{'min-width': '50rem'}"
            [rowHover]="true"
            [rows]="pageSize"
            [loading]="loading"
            [filterDelay]="0"
            [globalFilterFields]="['name','description','companyId']"
            [scrollable]="true"
            scrollHeight="flex">

      <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
        <div class="table-header">
          <p-button [label]="selectedCompany ? selectedCompany.name : 'Select company'" icon="pi pi-search"
                    (click)="op.toggle($event)">
          </p-button>Kategori Listesi<span class="p-input-icon-left"><i class="pi pi-search"></i>
          <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($any($event.target).value, 'contains')"
                placeholder="General search"/>
        </span>
        </div>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
          <th style="width:1%" pSortableColumn="id"></th>
          <th style="width:5%" pSortableColumn="id">Id<p-sortIcon field="id"></p-sortIcon></th>
          <th style="width:20%" pSortableColumn="name">Category name<p-sortIcon field="name"></p-sortIcon></th>
          <th style="width: 20%" pSortableColumn="companyId">Company Id<p-sortIcon field="companyId"></p-sortIcon></th>
          <th style="text-align: center; width: 20%"><button pButton pRipple autofocus type="button" icon="pi pi-plus" class="p-button-rounded p-button-outlined"
                                                            pAddRow [table]="dt" [newRow]="newRow()"></button></th>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template pTemplate="body"
                  let-rowDataCategory
                  let-editing="editing"
                  let-ri="rowIndex"
                  let-categories
                  let-expanded="expanded">
        <tr [pEditableRow]="rowDataCategory"
            [pContextMenuRow]="rowDataCategory"
            [ngClass]="{
            'editRecord': rowDataCategory.id === rowDataCategory.id.toString().indexOf(' '),
            'notRecord': !rowDataCategory.id.toString().indexOf(' ')}">
          <td>
            <button type="button"
                    pButton
                    pRipple
                    [pRowToggler]="categories"
                    class="p-button-text p-button-rounded p-button-plain"
                    [icon]="expanded ? 'pi pi-chevron-down' : 'pi pi-chevron-right'"></button>
          </td>
          <td>{{rowDataCategory.id}}</td>
          <td>
            <p-cellEditor>
              <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowDataCategory.name" pAutoFocus [autofocus]="true">
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template pTemplate="output">{{rowDataCategory.name}}</ng-template>
            </p-cellEditor>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p-cellEditor>
              <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                <p-dropdown [options]="companies"
                            optionLabel="name"
                            optionValue="id"
                            [(ngModel)]="cloneSelectedCompany"
                            scrollHeight='150px'>
                </p-dropdown>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template pTemplate="output">{{rowDataCategory.companyId}}</ng-template>
            </p-cellEditor>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center gap-2">
              <button *ngIf="!editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pInitEditableRow icon="pi pi-pencil" (click)="onCategoryRowEditInit(rowDataCategory)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text"></button>
              <button *ngIf="editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pSaveEditableRow icon="pi pi-check" (click)="onCategoryRowEditSave(rowDataCategory, ri)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-success mr-2"></button>
              <button *ngIf="editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" (click)="onCategoryRowEditCancel(rowDataCategory, ri)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-danger"></button>
              <button icon="pi pi-list" pButton pRipple class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-secondary"></button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>

      <!-- Row Expansion -->
      <ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-categories>
        <td colspan="7">
          <div class="p-p-3">
            <p-table #dtSub [value]="categories.categorySubs"
                    dataKey="id"
                    editMode="row">
              <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                  <th>Id</th>
                  <th pSortableColumn="name">Sub category name <p-sortIcon field="name"></p-sortIcon></th>
                  <th>Top Category Id</th>
                  <th style="text-align: center; width: 20%">
                    <button pButton pRipple autofocus type="button" icon="pi pi-plus"
                            class="p-button-rounded p-button-outlined" pAddRow [table]="dtSub"
                            [newRow]="newRow()">Sub category add</button>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>

              <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-categorySubs let-editing="editing" let-rowData let-ri="rowIndex">
                <tr [pEditableRow]="rowData"
                    [ngClass]="{
                    'editRecord': rowData.id === rowData.id.toString().indexOf(' '),
                    'notRecord': !rowData.id.toString().indexOf(' ')}">
                  <td>{{categorySubs.id}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <p-cellEditor>
                      <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.name" pAutoFocus [autofocus]="true">
                      </ng-template>
                      <ng-template pTemplate="output">{{rowData.name}}</ng-template>
                    </p-cellEditor>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <p-cellEditor>
                      <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData.categoryId">
                      </ng-template>
                      <ng-template pTemplate="output">{{rowData.categoryId}}</ng-template>
                    </p-cellEditor>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="flex align-items-center justify-content-center gap-2">
                      <button *ngIf="!editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pInitEditableRow icon="pi pi-pencil" (click)="onCategorySubRowEditInit(rowData)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text"></button>
                      <button *ngIf="editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pSaveEditableRow icon="pi pi-check" (click)="onCategorySubRowEditSave(rowData, ri)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-success mr-2"></button>
                      <button *ngIf="editing" pButton pRipple type="button" pCancelEditableRow icon="pi pi-times" (click)="onCategorySubRowEditCancel(rowData, ri)" class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-danger"></button>
                      <button icon="pi pi-list" pButton pRipple class="p-button-rounded p-button-text p-button-secondary"></button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="6">Empty data</td>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>
            </p-table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
  </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-category-list',
    templateUrl: './category-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./category-list.component.scss'],
    providers: [MessageService]
  })
  export class CategoryListComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
      private categoryService: CategoryService,
      private companyService: CompanyService,
      private messageService: MessageService,
      private primengConfig: PrimeNGConfig) { }


    //#table
    categoryList: CategoryModel[] = [];
    columns: [] | any;
    cols: any;
    page: number = 1;
    pageSize: number = 100;
    loading: boolean = true;
    totalRecords: number = 0;

    //overlay menu
    companies: CompanyModel[] = [];
    selectedCompany: any;
    cloneSelectedCompany: any;

    //#contextMenu
    contextMenu: MenuItem[] = [];
    selectedCategory: CategoryModel | any;

    clonedCategoryList: { [s: string]: CategoryModel } = {};
    rowCounter: number = 0;


    ngOnInit() {
      //this.getCompanyAllList();

      //ripple
      this.primengConfig.ripple = true;

      //#contextMenu
      this.contextMenu = [
        //{label: 'Refresh', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh', command: () => this.getCategoryList() },
        {label: 'Category delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-times', command: () => this.showConfirm(this.selectedCategory)}
      ];
    }

    //overlay
    onRowSelect(event: any) {
      this.messageService.add({severity: 'info', summary: 'select company', detail: event.data.name});
      this.selectedCompany = event.data;
      this.cloneSelectedCompany = event.data;

      //this.getCategoryList();
    }


    //addCategory
    addCategory(category: CategoryModel, index: number) {
      //console.log(category.id.toString().trim())
      category.id = category.id.toString().trim();

      this.categoryService.postCategory(category)
        .subscribe({
          next: (response: any) => {
            console.log(category)
            console.log(response)
            console.log(response.data)

            this.categoryList.push(response.data);
            this.categoryList = [...this.categoryList];
          },
          complete: () => {
            this.messageService.add({severity: 'success', summary: 'Başarılı', detail: `${category.name} isimli kategori kaydedildi.`, life: constants.TOAST_SUCCESS_LIFETIME});
            this.messageService.clear('c');

            this.categoryList[index] = this.clonedCategoryList[category.id];
            delete this.clonedCategoryList[category.id];
          },
          error: (e) => {
            this.messageService.add({severity: 'error', summary: 'Hata', detail: `kayıt yapılamadı \n${e}`, life: constants.TOAST_ERROR_LIFETIME});
            this.messageService.clear('c');
          }
        });
    }




    // --------------------------- Table Row ---------------------------
    //#Edit
    onCategoryRowEditInit(category: CategoryModel) {
      this.clonedCategoryList[category.id] = { ...category };
    }
    //#Save
    onCategoryRowEditSave(category: CategoryModel, index: number) {
      category.companyId = this.selectedCompany.id;

      if (!category.id.toString().indexOf(' ')){
        this.addCategory(category, index);
      } else if (category.id.toString().indexOf(' ')) {
        //this.putCategory(category);
      }
    }
    //#Cancel
    onCategoryRowEditCancel(category: CategoryModel, index: number) {
      this.categoryList[index] = this.clonedCategoryList[category.id];
      delete this.clonedCategoryList[category.id];
    }
    //#Pagination
    public handlePagination(paginationData: any): void {
      this.page = paginationData.page +1;
      this.pageSize = paginationData.rows;
      //this.getCategoryList();
    }
  // --------------------------- Table Row ---------------------------



    onReject() {
      this.messageService.clear('c');
    }

    showConfirm(selectedCompany: CategoryModel) {
      this.messageService.clear();
      this.messageService.add({key: 'c', sticky: true, severity:'warn', summary:'Silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz ?', detail:'Devam etmek için onaylayın'});
    }


    newRow() {
      return {
        id: ' '+this.rowCounter++,
        name: ''
      };
    }
  }
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: It redirects me to the addCategory field in typescript. But I don't see any areas here that I can fix or control.

Comment: I feel that is "this.clonedCategoryList[category.categoryId]" (see the `categoryId`) not "this.clonedCategoryList[category.id]"

Comment: yes i just noticed, i get the "category.id" number but "this.clonedCategoryList[category.id];" When I print its contents with console.log it is completely empty.